# Spring controller to an image causes it to not be displayed

Tags: spring-mvc

​I'm new to the spring mvc, and I need to manipulate the response for single image being loaded with a page. To do so, I added controller to this specific image

```
    @RequestMapping("/image.png")
    public void execute(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
       //some code will be here
    }
```

But writing that controller, even with no code in it, causes the image not to be displayed on the screen. Also, when I directly navigate to the image url it's still blank.
What could be the reason for that? Should the function return some value other than void? 
I'll appreciate any direction to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oups, you really should read some tutorial on Spring MVC. When you do not declare the controller, the url is (at end) processed by the servlet container that knows how to display png images.

But when you declare a controller for the url, it processes the request and *by convention*, either return a `View` indication for a `ViewResolver` (by returning a non null value), or declares that it fully processed the request by returning a void or null value.

In your example the controller returns a void value so it declares it fully processed the request and nothing else will happen.

But without you saying what you want to do, I cannot say how you could do it...